# What happens when I choose to ally with The God King in Infinity Blade?

Tags: ios, infinity-blade

I've already defeated The God King a couple times. When he offers the choice, will the game continue to loop infinitely as if I had beaten him? Or will the game end? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose to join him, you get the "Alternate Ending" achievement. There is a brief cutscene, the credits, and then it essentially loads the last checkpoint - it shows your character just before the battle again.

Comment: Lame, lol.... Thought you'd be able to get the infinity blade that way lol

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Nope, you have to grind the gold and buy it yourself.